# How to dynamically save two associated values into an array and access them in js?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I'm currently saving `$row 'id'` from my database into an array. This array is then sent using `json_encode` back to my JS file, where I access it. This is working fine.

My issue is that I'm struggling to figure out how to add `$row['vote_fb_name']` (string) to the same json callback array (in this case my callback is saved into `$feedback`)? `$row['vote_fb_uid']` and `$row['vote_fb_name']` appear in the same record.

**My PHP - here I save my id's into the array:**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
  $savedResultsInNewArray[] = $row['vote_fb_uid'];
}
$feedback = $savedResultsInNewArray;
```

**I then do my callback which is received by my js file:**

```
echo json_encode(array('returned_val' => $feedback));
```

**In my JS I then run a `for loop` to access the id's:**

```
for( var i = 0; i < data.returned_val.length; i++ ){
  var returnedId = data.returned_val[i];
  console.log("IDS HERE "+returnedId);
}
```

In this same `for loop` I'm looking to access the associated 'name'.

In PHP I figure I need to save my data as a two dimensional array, but how do I do that and afterwards how do I access it in my JS?

Comment: See [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method,

**In PHP code**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $feedback[] = array($row['vote_fb_uid'], $row['vote_fb_name']);
}
echo json_encode(array('returned_val' => $feedback));
```

**In JS**

```
for (i in data.returned_val) {
 console.log("IDS HERE "+data.returned_val[i][0]);
 console.log("NAME HERE "+data.returned_val[i][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as a matter of fact, $feedback is already a 2-d array

```
$feedback = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
     $feedback[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode(array('returned_val' => $feedback));
```

or, in case of using [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

```
echo json_encode(array('returned_val' => $stmt->fetchAll()));
```

of course you need to se

Answer (score 0):

You could have your `$row['vote_fb_uid']` be your array keys

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $savedResultsInNewArray[$row['vote_fb_uid']] = $row['vote_fb_name'];
}
$feedback = $savedResultsInNewArray;
```